# Laravel auth scaffolding returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I am running the latest Laravel 5.3 version, and after running `php artisan make:auth`, I attempt to logout within the application and it returns this error: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

Web.php (routes file):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'ClinicController@index');
```

I can see that the views have been created, but why is it returning this error? Many thanks in advance

Comment: did you added any new `routes` to the genrated `laravel auth route` as I don't see `Route::auth();` after running `php artisan make:auth`.

Comment: please make sure in this file `/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` this line `  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }` is ther

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel 5.3 `/logout` route is assigned to method `POST`, so to log out you have to create form and submit it.

```
<form action="{{ route('/logout') }}" method="post">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just manually and follow line to your `web/routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```